# Linux: Creating hard links on a portable music player

Tags: ubuntu-10.10

Whenever I try to create a link on my 16GB Walkman to another file on the Walkman, I get the error "Operation not permitted". This happens whether I'm trying to create a hard or soft link, and whether I'm sending the command as myself or as root (with sudo). Does anyone know why I can't do this and if there is any way around it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Music players are usually formatted as FAT16 or FAT32, neither of which supports soft or hard links. There is no filesystem-level way around this.

Comment: Well, darn. Thanks for the prompt and clear response.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need both filesystem and OS support for softlinks, hardlinks or symlinks. Most portable media players use really simple filesystems underneath, fat32 for players that are accessible as a mass storage devices (or MTP), or various vendor specific filesystems for [ptp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picture_Transfer_Protocol), and basic OSes. If it was one of the newer android based players, then it would use an ext varient and this might work.

While, in theory you could reformat a mass storage class device to a file system that supports these features, the simple OS on most PMPs wouldn't support it. That said, this sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - you might be able to get a better solution by focusing on *why* you want/need to link that file.